# Querying number of subscription to each publication

Tags: sql-server, merge-replication

We have a production box that has about 60 publications on it. Some of these are used, and some seem to not be... What I need to do is create, or find, a script that will get the count of subscribers/subscriptions per publication so I can easily identify unused publications.

We are using SQL Server 2005. :(

Thank you,
Wes

Comment: Is `MSmerge_subscriptions` what you're looking for? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188905(v=sql.110).aspx

Comment: Yes, it was....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get the necessary info I needed by poking around a bit:

```
use Distribution; 
select count(s.publisher_id) as 'Number of Subscribers', p.publication_id, p.Publisher_db, p.publication from MSpublications p
    left outer join MSmerge_subscriptions s on p.publication_id = s.publication_id

 group by p.publication_id, p.publisher_db, p.publication
 Order by Publisher_db, Publication_id asc
```

Answer (score 1):

Below script will give you information for all databases with replication info:

```
-- For Merge replication
-- Author: Kin Shah

DECLARE @Detail CHAR(1) 
SET @Detail = 'Y' 
CREATE TABLE #tmp_replcationInfo 
    ( 
    articlename VARCHAR(128),  
    publisherserver VARCHAR(128), 
    publisherdb VARCHAR(128), 
    publicationname VARCHAR(128),
    subscriberservername VARCHAR(128) 
    ) 
EXEC sp_msforeachdb  
'use ?; 
IF DATABASEPROPERTYEX ( db_name() , ''IsMergePublished'' ) = 1 
insert into #tmp_replcationInfo 
select distinct 
    sa.name as articlename,
    sp.publisher as publisherserver,
    sp.publisher_db as publisherdb,
    sp.name as publicationname
    ,ss.subscriber_server as subscriberservername 
from dbo.sysmergearticles sa
join dbo.sysmergepublications sp on sa.pubid = sp.pubid
join dbo.sysmergesubscriptions ss on ss.pubid = sa.pubid
order by subscriberservername
' 
IF @Detail = 'Y' 
   SELECT * FROM #tmp_replcationInfo 
ELSE 
print 'nothing to display !! '
DROP TABLE #tmp_replcationInfo
```